# A certain div isn't raising an event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onmouseover

**Problem:**

One HTML div isn't raising an event on `mouseover` as the other one does.

**Details:**

- Both divs are identical in every way except id
- My Javascript code has been tested to work correctly
- Both divs reside in the same parent container
- Changing the event type doesn't help

**[Edit 3] Difficulty of this question:**

This issue was so hard to solve as websites such as fiddle which people use to solve problems like this don't actually have the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration at the top.

**[Edit 2] Another Video:**

Please view this video as I try to explain what is going on:

https://solomonbroadbentnz-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/NjQ0OTE2XzMxMzM0NTM

**[Edit 1] More resources:**

Obviously, I haven't done a very good job of this question as it hasn't been well received by some.

Here is a git repo with the full source code:

https://github.com/solomonbroadbent/test

And a video of the issue:

https://solomonbroadbentnz-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/NjQ0NTg4XzMxMzI2OTM

I am actively trying to improve this question, so any suggestions are welcome.

**Code:**

This is basically what is happening:

```
<!--Necessary HTML code...-->
    <div id='divA' onmouseover='abitraryJSFunction()'></div> <!--event works-->
    <div i='divB' onmouseover='abitraryJSFunction()'></div> <!--event fails-->
    <!-- javascript file call -->
<!--Neccisary HTML code...-->
```

**More Specific Code:**

This what I am actually trying to achieve:

HTML

```
<div id='leftDiv' onmouseover='showDragTab()'>
</div>
<div id='pageDiv' onmouseover='hideDragTab()'>
</div>
<div id='dragTab'>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function showDragTab() 
{
    myDragTab.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function hideDragTab()
{
    myDragTab.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: what is `</>`? Close your divs properly as `</div>`..

Comment: Why the downvote? If I may ask, I'm happy to adjust my post...

Comment: Even if I fix the obvious syntax errors, [things work as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/63y13o6y/). Please make sure your question includes an [mcve] if possible.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm working on it now

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: After your most recent edit, there's still bits of code missing to form a [mcve]. If I imagine what those bits of code look like, [things work as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/padzw3n6/). Please help us reproduce the issue, without that we can't really help you.

Comment: @Jeroen could you please check out the latest video I posted with audio.

Comment: @Lal could you please check out the latest video I posted with audio.

Comment: @Squighopper25 ftfy. Hope it works, you're killing me here man. :P (see my 3rd edit)

Comment: PS in your video you are passing a function to window.onload AND calling it. You should just pass the function, this could be another source of your trouble. In any case check my latest fiddle and you can see it working.

Comment: @Damon Yeah, I seem to have fixed the issue now... Cheers for all your help. The solution was pretty weird

Comment: Glad you resolved it. Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer ? (since it is the only answer anyway). Sucks that someone downvoted it - not sure why.

Comment: @Damon If you see my latest answer that resolved it.

Comment: Interesting, didn't notice that since I moved it to fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution:**

At the top of the file, I changed `<!DOCTYPE = html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

**Details:**

This resulted in me needing to change my font sizes slightly, but it now works.

[Edit]:  That was literally all. Using previous versions of my git repo, I could even prove my code was correct the entire time...

Thanks, for everyone's help with this question, especially SO user Damon.